# Popularity of Alexa?

Tags: red

Can anyone explain the reason behind the Alexa's immense popularity among feature films? I see that it is the significant favorite over the Red Epic which is its closest competitor. Why is this? Is is the brand name? Please excuse my technical ignorance but doesn't the red epic dragon shoot 6K and the Alexa 3.2K? Shouldn't this just make the Red epic dragon the go-to camera rather than the Alexa?

Comment: I like your question, but it is primarily opinion-based, might be better to rephrase it, because the answer is a mix of personal preferences and especially requirements on the project. The sum of all is crucial for the frequent use of Alexa's, further resolution has nothing to do with quality.

Comment: Please elaborate on why resolution has nothing to do with quality.

Comment: That's another question ;) In short: you can buy a trillion megapixel camera, but the quality of an image is determined by several other things, like: the quality of the sensor (noise, dynamic range), the sensor size, the sensitivity of the sensor in low light situations, the image processor, the range of lenses you can use and so on... See: http://lifehacker.com/5912356/what-specs-actually-matter-in-a-digital-camera - It's photography only, but a solid start to dive in :)